# Printing an array with input from user. Returning first value a zero?

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I'm not exactly sure what I have done but my goal is to accept 10 numbers from the user and store them into an array. In which I can then print back out in order received. I believe I have accomplished that with the exception of the first value is defaulting to zero in the output and I am not sure how to fix that. Any help?

```
package array;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[10];

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter ten numbers: ");
        input.nextInt();

        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
            a[j]=input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your number list is:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I pasted the wrong code initially. I tried playing around to skip index 0 to see if that made a difference. It didn't of course.

Comment: You don't take 10 inputs here, just want to point.

Comment: it should now I believe. I updated the code

Comment: @JonathanRoberts You can't enter ten numbers into an array of only nine elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array should be sized to `10` (and your loop test should also be `10`, or better - use the array `length`). You should use braces, it helps prevent subtle bugs. And I see no reason to discard the first `int`. Putting it all together like,

```
int[] a = new int[10];
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter ten numbers: ");
for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    a[j] = input.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Your number list is: ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong but does the array index not start at zero? So calling for 10 places would actually output 11, no?

Comment: @JonathanRoberts Valid indices in the array are `0` to `length - 1`. So the above has space for ten elements, and valid indices are `0` to `9` inclusive.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you've defined an array of `9` elements, not `10`.

change this:

```
int[] a = new int[9];
```

to this:

```
int[] a = new int[10];
```

also, change this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
```

to this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
```

Lastly but not least these two statements should not be inside the loop:

```
System.out.println("Your number list is: ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

place them outside the loop.

```
for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
     a[j] = input.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("Your number list is:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```